# Google Recaptcha Always Return False

Tags: php, phpmailer, recaptcha

I am integrating a new Google recaptcha for my customer , i tired on my working server , everything working correctly , but on client server , its go (!$captcha) part.
Seems like Json responding false every time , i tried with different method but failed.

**Here is my code :**

```
ob_start();
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                        // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "";   // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "";               // SMTP password


$Name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$Subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$Remarks = $_REQUEST['remarks'];

$mail->From = "";
$mail->FromName = "Vision Pilates Enquiry Form";

$mail->AddAddress("", "Admin");
//$mail->AddAddress("ellen@example.com");                  // name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("$Email", "$Name");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
//$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Enquiry from website: $Subject";
$mail->Body    = "<strong>Name:</strong> $Name <br><strong>Email:</strong> $Email <br><strong>Subject:</strong> $Subject <br><strong>Remarks:</strong> $Remarks <br>"; 
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    //form submitted

    //check if other form details are correct

    //verify captcha
    if (!$captcha) {
        echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
        exit;
    }
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret==SecretKey=&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if ($response . success == false) {
        echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    } else {
        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            header("location: error.htm");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("location: sent.htm");
        }
    }
}
```

after submit end result is

### Please check the the captcha form.

.

Thanks

Comment: Any one ? Who can help?

Comment: you are sending data via get not post you must use curl

Answer (score 2):

the method must `post` according to the [recaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request)

> API Request
>
> URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
>
> METHOD: POST

```
function VerifyRecaptcha($g_recaptcha_response) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
            'secret' => 'your secret goes here <<<<<<<',
            'response' => $g_recaptcha_response,
            'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        )
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    if($result = curl_exec($ch)){
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($result);
        return $response->success;
    }else{
        var_dump(curl_error($ch)); // this for debug remove after you test it
        return false;
    }
}
```

then use it like that

```
if(!VerifyRecaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
{
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things in a funny order. Check the captcha before setting up anything else - if the captcha is wrong, you are not going to need the PHPMailer instance.

I also suspect your URL is broken:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret==SecretKey=&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

You have an extra `=` in there, and you're not escaping your params. That may result in an invalid URL - recaptcha usually asks for two words, and spaces are not valid in URLs, so I suggest you do this:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SecretKey=&response=" . rawurlencode($captcha) . "&remoteip=" . rawurlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer; Please [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).